# How to create a survey with some options in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create survey. I have below models:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()


class SurveyOptions(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, related_name='s_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

the `survey` options might be 2 or 3 or 10 or etc.

How can I create that? I don't know how to create a form for it.
I googled it, but I didn't find any useful links. I need an example of it. thanks.

Comment: I think you haven't explored enough yet visit this : https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/survey-questionnaire/

Comment: @Gahan I want to create surveys without using any third-party packages.

Comment: then you are not even yet sure on what to do next. if it's just about having relation then use ManytoMany relation instead of foreign key

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2):

To create a survey, you really want predefined fields for users to select choices. Here is an example from Django's [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in (self.JUNIOR, self.SENIOR)
```

You can then use Django's [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) to create a form from the model itself.

I hope this helps!